# How to get list of updated fields in inlineformset in django

Tags: django-forms

I have a inlineformset with few fields. Like in forms we have changed_data which gives list of updated fields, is there any attribute like that for inlineformset?
Or any other procedure to find the list of updated fields?If any procedure please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the formset and append them to the list.

```
for form in formset:
    updated_fields.append(form.changed_data)
```